# Drools Rule execution delays the first time after updating rules

Tags: drools

In Drools v7.32.0.Final, the first time a KieSession of a KieBase fires the rules when the program starts, or whenever a new jar is deployed, execution time of rules is approximately 5 times more than the average time later on.
I have seen posts referring to v6.x with the same problem, suggesting to do a dummy execution of rules, because the problem is indexing. I have done dummy executions, passing in drools all the objects that i am currently using with empty fields and the only improvement i got is to go to 4 times slower.

Can anyone suggest a solution? If the problem is indexing as mentioned, is there a way to force KieBases to index before executing any rules?

Comment: Have you tried debugging or doing an analysis to figure out where the time is actually spent?

Comment: Furthering that thought, are you creating the kie bases and related as soon as the update is received, or waiting until the first request in order to actually load them? (Lazy load/init or eager?)

Comment: I have created static volatile kieBases ( cause new sessions are created continuously). Those bases are created/updated when the update happens.  In that way i thought that kieSession that will be created from the base will be fully ready